# Data processing in Spout in Apache Storm

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-storm

We are trying to a build a real time notification system and using Apache Storm for it .

For this , we have a message Broker (RabbitMq)  which takes care of getting the data from the publishers and pushing it to Subscribers using Listners at the subscriber end.

Now , I need to do some processing on each event  which is received by the message Broker (make some calls to database and based on that we need to decide if we want to process it or not further ) .

Ideally , the storm should read the event data from the stream (Message Broker in our case) . But since we have to do some operations on the event and decide whether or not it should be feed to the bolts for processing , shall I do that logic inside my Spout or shall I have a seperate component say a kind of dispatcher which shall be sending it to the Spout .  Basically , should spout contain the business logic of any kind ? Also , considering that we have millions of events coming in a second , is it good enough to put this much load on the spout .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no problem in putting logic within a Spout. You only need to consider the following: the thread that executes the method `Spout.nextTuple()` does have some additional duties. For example, it receives ack and fail messages for processed tuples and times-out emitted tuples (in case no ack is received on time). For this to happen, it is essential, that you do not stay "forever" (ie, loop or block) in `.nextTuple()` but return after emitting a tuple to the system (or just return if no tuple can be emitted, but not block). Otherwise, the Spout cannot does its work properly. `nextTuple()` will be called in a loop by Storm. Thus, after ack/fail messages are processed etc. the next call to `nextTuple()` happens quickly.

In your case, if you return after checking a tuple if it needs processing should be ok. Just return from `.nextTuple()` after discarding or emitting a single tuple to the system. You might want to consider the time you need to come to a conclusion about a single tuple, ie, the time you spent within `nextTuple()`. If it is too long, you might need to increase the message timeout.